# Listening continuously on TCP client

Tags: c#, xamarin, c#-4.0, tcp, xamarin.forms

Can someone guide me on listening on TCP Client continuously using C#.

I am able to send a command and receive the response. But my requirement is once we establish the connection, server will be sending the messages and I need to keep the connection open.

I don't want to follow a polling mechanism for various reasons such as performance. I need to get this working on a mobile client (developing using Xamarin).

I wrote the following code but it's not working as expected. It's connecting to the server and sending the messages. But not receiving any messages/not able to handle the received response.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {   
        var client = new SocketClient();
        client.Connect();

        client.InitConnection();
        client.Listen(Listen);
    }

    private static bool Listen(byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: response received");
            string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Null buffer");
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class SocketClient
{
    private bool terminate_listening = false;
    private TcpClient mainClient = null;

    public SocketClient()
    {
        mainClient = new TcpClient();
    }

    public bool Connected => mainClient.Connected;

    public void Connect()
    {
        var port = 5020;
        mainClient.Connect("host", 5020);
    }

    public void InitConnection()
    {

        Write($"some message");
    }

    public void Write(string message)
    {
        // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "(char)4");
        NetworkStream stream = mainClient.GetStream();
        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);
    }

    const int MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 1024;

    public void Listen(Func<byte[], bool> processDataFunc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in listen");
        Byte[] data_buffer = new Byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

        if (!this.Connected)
        {
            this.Connect();
        }
        NetworkStream stream = mainClient.GetStream();

        while (!this.terminate_listening)
        {
            while (stream.Read(data_buffer, 0, data_buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                processDataFunc(data_buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Naresh

Comment: "*I wrote the following code but it's not working as expected.*" - Please clarify this. What is it doing, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot thanks for highlighting. I have just updated my question. Hopefully it's clear.

Comment: Look into something like SignalR client for Xamarin.

Comment: @Naresh are you sure? you are receiving data from server. Read is a blocking call it will keep waiting until there is some data to read or the connection is not closed or no data is available to read. And have you tried putting Listen function (where you are reading data from server) to try-catch. You might be getting some runtime exception in this function.